# php how to read file json with array including numbers inside each number different data?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have output file json but i can't read the properties in array [0]

```
 contacts: 
      Array(20)
                0: 
                 canonical-vid:00000
                 form-submissions:[]
                 identity-profiles:[{…}]
                 is-contact:true
                 merge-audits:[]
                 merged-vids:[]
                 portal-id:000000
                 properties:{....}
```

I use this code in php :

```
    $json = file_get_contents('./file,json');

    $data = json_decode($json,true);

    $firstname = $data['contacts'][0]['properties']['firstname']['value'];
```

Comment: dump and debug index by index, i think maybe $data['contacts'][0]['properties'] is not in correct type, so dump it.

Comment: What data does `properties` contain? Do you get an error message? Wrong firstname? Blank page?

Comment: properties contain first name and value

Comment: i get blank page

Answer (score 0):

I think $data['contacts'][0]['properties'] is json. Try like this:

```
$properties = $data['contacts'][0]['properties'];
$nameData = json_decode($properties,true);
```